# dynamically creating nested loops with variable ranges

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, loops

I'm trying to construct a mechanism that takes start, stop, step arguments of other functions and returns every possible combination with an output that is referenced to each input range.

I was thinking of using a for loop for each set of arguments received, with each additional loop being nested.

The arguments received by the mechanism are information regarding a range of variables to be iterated through.

I'm aiming to do this using numpy iteration to speed up the calculation after implementing numba but I will take anything as long as it's fast.

```
import numpy as np

def numpy_range(start, stop, step):

    return np.nditer(np.arange(start,stop,step))

def function_with_values():
    do something
    return 0, 3, 1

def function_with_values_2():
    do something
    return 1, 4, 1
         
def assign_param_loops(function_with_values(), function_with_values_2()):
    do something
    return nested loops (function_with_values, function_with_values_2)

#function_with_values
for param1 in numpy_range(0, 3, 1):
            
     #function_with_values_2
    for param2 in numpy_range(1, 4, 1):
        
        print(param1, param2)
```

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
```

As you can see, I aim to create a new loop for each function added into the assign_param_loops() function.

But really any method that allows me to input multiple sets of start, stop, step numbers and output every possible combination between them will do as long as each set of inputs are linked to their own output variable.

Dynamic loop creation is just the only method I can think of.
As far as I know, itertools won't work because I don't think there's a way to dynamically link the outputs to its inputs.

For example this could work

```
import itertools

args = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]


for [*numbers] in itertools.product(*args):

    print([numbers[0], numbers[1]])
```

but then I need a way to dynamically add numbers[0], numbers[1] (and beyond) as more inputs are added

I've looked around but I haven't been able to find anything that suits this purpose.
Does anyone have any ideas?

***edit***
This is the closest I've gotten so far

```
import itertools

args = []
names = []


def range_list(start, stop, step, name):
    global range_counter
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(start, stop+1, step):
        temp_list.append(i)
    args.append(temp_list)
    names.append(name)



range_list(0,3,1,"param1")
range_list(0,3,1,"param2")



    
for [*numbers] in itertools.product(*args):
    
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        name = names[i]

        print(name, [numbers[i]])
```

Which outputs

```
param1 [0]
param2 [0]
param1 [0]
param2 [1]
param1 [0]
param2 [2]
param1 [0]
param2 [3]
param1 [1]
param2 [0]
param1 [1]
param2 [1]
param1 [1]
param2 [2]
param1 [1]
param2 [3]
param1 [2]
param2 [0]
param1 [2]
param2 [1]
param1 [2]
param2 [2]
param1 [2]
param2 [3]
param1 [3]
param2 [0]
param1 [3]
param2 [1]
param1 [3]
param2 [2]
param1 [3]
param2 [3]
```

Although it's still not usable.

The issue with itertools is it produces all combinations at once, and I need it to output each combination one at a time so it can be placed within a for loop and fed into other functions.

Does anyone know of a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `numpy` iteration does not speed up anything - unless you are using compiled numpy methods.  List iteration is faster.  `np.nditer` is not a speed tool, though it may a useful way of testing ideas that will be ported to cython.

Comment: I do intend to use cython and numba in the end.

Comment: I read through your description 3x and still don't grok what you want to achieve - maybe you should try to reformulate in a more algorithmic way - "output referenced to input range" e.g. is something I can't really figure out.